# How to port forward UDP in local area network over wifi sharing/tether

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, tethering, wifi-tethering

This is an offline situation.

#### The phone is already capable of tethering without an internet connection

I'm trying to setup a multiplayer game using an android phone as the router. It requires port forwarding with UDP.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: did you try this: [{Guide} How To Obtain an Open Nat (Phone Tethering)](https://androidforums.com/threads/guide-how-to-obtain-an-open-nat-phone-tethering.795221/)